# Angular material design: mdThemingProvider and Color palettes, how to use them

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I'm very new to Angular's material design and I'm finding it hard to locate and proper tutorial for beginners. I am wanting to know if it is possible to use a predefined color palette(css) with the $mdThemingProvider? Is there any proper documentation that can explain to me what $mdThemingProvider actually does code wise. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

While it is possible to style your AngularJS Material Design objects with CSS (like any other HTML elements), it is not the recommended way. Instead, the AngularJS Material Design package provides us with themes that will allow for simple full-ui color changes in the future (and for our users to pick).

Firstly, [read this page](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme). From a code standpoint, it truly is what you need to know. You'll want to reference it often.

Secondly, and unfortunately, they don't really offer an easy way to create a new palette of colors for within your theme. In order to do that, you need to specify a hex code for all of the main color options in a palette OR extend a default palette and modify just a couple colors. I've created a theme generator to help you through this process and make things a little easier, [which you can use here](http://mcg.mbitson.com/).

Thirdly, the big one when coming from more traditional setups is the need for "Warning" or "Success" themes that allow for operation-oriented themeing instead of site-wide themeing. There are many discussions about this across the net, but I'd recommend creating a theme for each of these typical "states" for use throughout your application. This allows you to use secondary palettes within any particular state- like being able to invert a warning theme without needing to rewrite the CSS. [Here is a discussion](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/537#issuecomment-146980110) about this.

In the end- it takes a change in perspective to theme with this package, much like it did when using AngularJS the first time after jQuery/Prototype.

Cheers!

Answer (score -3):

I have started with this:

[Configuring a theme](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/docs/content/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme.md)